# Selenium Webdriver.csproce Compilation issue in C#.net on DevTools V85, V91 & V92

Tags: c#, selenium

I am getting compilation error on C#.net WebDriver.csproj as below

These are the reference are missing and I not seeing any code for this classes

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V85.Log
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V85.Page;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V85.Runtime;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V85.Fetch;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V85.Network;
```

[image]

[image]

why is this reference error appearing and how to solve this?
Am missing something on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't import them like this, you can try to access the objects directly.

Also [this guide](https://dotjord.wordpress.com/2020/09/13/how-to-capture-network-activity-with-selenium-4-in-asp-net-core-3-1/) can help you to get started.

There is an [official guide](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/support_packages/chrome_devtools/) from Selenium if you are using an 4.0 alpha how to interact with dev tools.

I will share the snipet here I'm currently using.

```
IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
DevToolsSession session = devTools.CreateDevToolsSession();
session.Network.ResponseReceived += ResponseReceivedHandler;
session.Network.Enable(new EnableCommandSettings());
```

```
public void ResponseReceivedHandler(object sender, ResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine($"Status: { e.Response.Status } : {e.Response.StatusText} | File: 
   { e.Response.MimeType } | Url: { e.Response.Url } ");
}
```